# Can I use jQuery.extend to simulate method overloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite familiar with jQuery. I'm trying to write common methods for my own purpose. Here is a sample below:

```
$.extend({
    add  : function(a, b)
           {
             return a + b;
           },

    add  : function(a, b, c)
           {
             return a + b + c;
           }
   });
```

Is the above scenario possible? Can I use the same extender name and pass different parameters, like method overloading?

Comment: I think that will just overwrite the first 'add' property with the 2nd

Comment: I assume you meant "overloading". But as alex notes, the second function *will* **override** the first...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to do some type of what is called in some languages *method overloading*.

JavaScript doesn't supports it in that way.

JavaScript is very versatile and lets you achieve this kind of feature in different ways.

For your particular example, your `add` function, I would recommend you to make a function that accepts an arbitrary number of parameters, using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery, {
  add: function (/*arg1, arg2, ..., argN*/) {
    var result = 0;

    $.each(arguments, function () {
      result += this;
    });

    return result;
  }
});
```

Then you can pass any number of arguments:

```
alert(jQuery.add(1,2,3,4)); // shows 10
```

For more complex method overloading you can detect the number of arguments passed and its types, for example:

```
function test () {
  if (arguments.length == 2) { // if two arguments passed
    if (typeof arguments[0] == 'string' && typeof arguments[1] == 'number') {
      // the first argument is a string and the second a number
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

Check the following article, it contains a very interesting technique that takes advantage of some JavaScript language features like closures, function application, etc, to mimic *method overloading*:

- [JavaScript method overloading](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/)

Comment: It's late and I'm probably reading your code wrong but wouldn't `jQuery.add(1,2,3,4)` return `10`?

Comment: His function uses a magic pattern parser, and determined the next number in sequence to be 5 ;)

Comment: add: function (/*arg1, arg2, ..., argN*/)
How will the above code be?
add: function (a,b,c,d,e???) {

Comment: @engineerachu: You don't need to declare any input arguments, `/*arg1, arg2, ..., argN*/` is just a comment to let know that this function can accept any number of arguments, in fact it could just be: `add: function (){`

Comment: My scenario is like, I need to call "copyRow" method where one may have 2 parameter and other may have 3 paramaters. Eg:

$.extend({
       copyRow : function(obj, chkBoxID)
       {
               // Do operation
       },
       copyRow  : function(obj, ChkBoxID, count)
       {
            // Do operation
       }
});

Is the above possible with the method you gave?

Comment: @CMS: Your answer is totally right and should be accepted. However, there is one more possibility you have. You could use an object as the one and only argument and that object might contain a different number of properties.

Answer (score 3):

I think that will just overwrite the first 'add' property with the 2nd 'add' property you defined. This is useful when developing plugins, and want to provide a list of sensible defaults for a config object.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not throw errors if you pass fewer arguments to a function than it is defined to accept.

You can use a variable arguments set-up in your function using "arguments", or you could just define your function as you had in the 2nd statement (with 3 parameters) and simply check if the 3rd parameter is undefined.  If an argument isn't supplied, it is set as undefined and you can simply check for that (it's not the same as null) which may be simpler than having to use the arguments object.